# How to make all the contents appear in dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

I have given HTML and CSS code but whenever I click on the dropdown menu the options appear but they hide until I hover my mouse on that particular item. Only hovered item appears.

[image]

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select name="payment_method" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_payment_method">
  <option value="">-------</option>
  <option value="easypaisa" selected="">EasyPaisa Number</option>
  <option value="jazzcash">Jazzcash Number</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Somewhere else lies your problem. From given HTML and CSS, it works in fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/0xt1yLfh/

Comment: It is working but the picture link which I have given please see it

Comment: As you can see in the picture, the color of the text for the select is set to white. What do you expect to happen if you command white text on white background?

Comment: So change color: inherit; to color: #000; or color: black;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.075);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select name="payment_method" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_payment_method">
  <option value="">-------</option>
  <option value="easypaisa" selected="">EasyPaisa Number</option>
  <option value="jazzcash">Jazzcash Number</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sunil your answer worked correctly but there is one problem. I am working in django and I downloaded template and made changes in main.css but it is not working. All the files I downloaded was from inspect because in django I wrote it as ```{{form}}``` How to deal with that?

Comment: .formclass .select.form-control{ /**style goes here **/ }, if CSS not working the use !important